# Save doesn't work correct

Tags: animation

I have a big problem and I can't solve them. When I save the project it always save false. On the second picture you can see the project that I want to save. In the first picture you can see the false saved version. Before there was so much more text. Funny is that it always saves the same version no matter what I do. I am very sad because I lose a lot of work. Please help me out. Thank you for your help.[image][image]

Comment: Are the objects animated? Could be that you forgot to update the keyframe and it move back to the original position.

Comment: Omg thank you so much, yes I forgot it to update them.

Comment: Great! I'll add this as an answer then, so others can find it easier.

Answer (score 2):

The objects were moved but their keyframes for the location weren't updated. Once you re-open the file they will snap back to their original keyframe location. To update the position of an object select the frame you want to edit in the timeline, then move the object to the desired position and press <kbd>I</kbd>. Select *Location* from the menu or a combination that includes the location.